# Mute music played in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, frontend

So I have an iframe whose "src" points to the URL of some music. The iframe is hidden and it plays the music automatically. How do I add a button to mute the music?

```
<iframe hidden="true" frameborder="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width=330 height=86
        src="http://urlofmusic"></iframe>
```

Note that the music is from an external website. Also the URL doesn't point to a particular file. It's simply an external link provided by the website.

Comment: Could you provide your code so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: is `http://urlofmusic` pointing to some audio file ? (`.mp3`) Is this file on the same server than your page? If those two conditions are true, then you can access it via `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('video')` then simply change its `muted` property to `true`if you just want to mute it or even call its `pause()` method.

Comment: Is the music being played via an HTML5 tag or with Flash?

Comment: Then you're screwed, the only way being removing the iframe

Comment: @Kaiido what if the conditions you mentioned are true? Why did you use querySelector('video') since it's a .mp3 file?

Comment: Well give it a try, you'll find that browsers do parse Media files in a video element, no matter if it's an audio file or a video one

Comment: I don't think you can access element inside a frame. You will get a permission error. Take a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: @takid1412 except if the document you're accessing is on the same domain as the parent page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to mute a iframe is remove it from html. You can clone it for unmute later. But you cannot pause and resume, it like stop and play.

**HTML**

```
<div id = "iframe_contain">
    <iframe width="0" height="0" hidden="hidden" id="iframe"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/y6120QOlsfU?autoplay=1&loop=1">
    </iframe>
</div>
<a href="javascript:" id="mute">Mute</a><a href="javascript:" id="unmute">Unmute</a>
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
    $("#mute").click(mute);
    $("#unmute").click(unmute);
    //backup iframe
    var iframe_bk;
    //play status
    var status = 1;
    function mute(){
        if(status!=1) return;
        var iframe = $("#iframe");
        iframe_bk = iframe.clone();
        iframe.remove();
        status = 0;
    }
    function unmute(){
        if(status!=0) return;
        if(iframe_bk){
            $("#iframe_contain").append(iframe_bk);
            iframe_bk = null;
            status = 1;
        }
    }
})();
```

I use jQuery and here working version in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aydv9x1r/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "controls" parameter inside the audio tag

```
<audio controls>
<source src="nameofsong.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="nameofsong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
audio tag not supported message optional
</audio>
```

You can substitute the filename for the URL of the song in the src

Comment: You can refer to my edition above. The url is not pointing to any music file. Instead it is the address of the entire iframe provided by the external website.